# Unable to connect to AWS S3 from a react js app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use aws-sdk and connect to AWS S3(bucket is created in AWS account), from a react js app. However, the very import line if causing the error:

import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

If above import is removed, the app home page in localhost shows up, but if above line if there, the app shows a white blank screen

Other libraries like react-s3 and react-aws-s3 failes to work too

Can you please help me through this situation

Comment: Can you provide the component code, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: referenceError: global is not defined
I get above error in console. there are some solutions that say I need to add a piece of code to polyfills.ts but it is not clear

Comment: You use CRA or vite?

Comment: Vite is used here

Comment: Check my answer, i added the change to made in vite config file inside define block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the global reference issue you can add the following script to your index.html

```
<script>
 if (global === undefined) {
  var global = window;
 }
</script>
```

If you are using vite try this

```
export default defineConfig({
 define: {
   global: {},
 },
})
```

Another way to do it is to create a js file with the following content and then import it

```
window.global ||= window;
```